# Issues upgrading to Mongodb v7 on Ubuntu 20 - Failed with result 'core-dump'

Tags: mongodb, installation, ubuntu-20.04

I was upgrading from v4 to v7 and now can't get past 'core-dump'

I started by removing anything mongodb related from the server

```
user@monitor:~$ sudo apt remove --purge mongodb-org-*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-tools' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-mongos' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-tools' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-database-tools-extra' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-server' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-shell' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-shell' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-mongos' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-database-tools-extra' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-tools-unstable' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-database' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-server' for glob 'mongodb-org-*'
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-database-tools-extra' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-mongos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-unstable-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-tools-unstable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-database-tools-extra' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-database' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-shell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mongodb-org-tools' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb-org-mongos* mongodb-org-server*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 311 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 141132 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-mongos (7.0.2) ...
Removing mongodb-org-server (7.0.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
(Reading database ... 141115 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for mongodb-org-server (7.0.2) ...
```

Then I check that there's nothing left installed mongo-related

```
user@monitor:~$ sudo apt list --installed | grep mongo

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

I added the apt list:

```
user@monitor:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse
```

and proceeded to install

```
user@monitor:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-mongosh mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-database-tools-extra mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-mongosh mongodb-org mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-database-tools-extra mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 57.5 MB/156 MB of archives.
After this operation, 530 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-shell amd64 7.0.2 [3080 B]
Get:2 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-server amd64 7.0.2 [34.0 MB]
Get:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-mongos amd64 7.0.2 [23.6 MB]
Get:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-database-tools-extra amd64 7.0.2 [7720 B]
Get:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-database amd64 7.0.2 [3536 B]
Get:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-tools amd64 7.0.2 [2892 B]
Fetched 57.5 MB in 2s (26.2 MB/s)           
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-database-tools.
(Reading database ... 141115 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-mongodb-database-tools_100.8.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.8.0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-mongosh.
Preparing to unpack .../1-mongodb-mongosh_2.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-mongosh (2.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
Preparing to unpack .../2-mongodb-org-shell_7.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (7.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-server.
Preparing to unpack .../3-mongodb-org-server_7.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (7.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
Preparing to unpack .../4-mongodb-org-mongos_7.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (7.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-database-tools-extra.
Preparing to unpack .../5-mongodb-org-database-tools-extra_7.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-database-tools-extra (7.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-database.
Preparing to unpack .../6-mongodb-org-database_7.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-database (7.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../7-mongodb-org-tools_7.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (7.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
Preparing to unpack .../8-mongodb-org_7.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (7.0.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-mongosh (2.0.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-server (7.0.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-shell (7.0.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-database-tools (100.8.0) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (7.0.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-database-tools-extra (7.0.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-database (7.0.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-tools (7.0.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-org (7.0.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

Doesn't seem like there were any problems, but a fresh install won't start.

```
user@monitor:~$ systemctl start mongod
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'mongod.service'.
Authenticating as: user
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===

user@monitor:~$ systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Tue 2023-10-17 17:06:38 EDT; 2s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 104443 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
   Main PID: 104443 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

Oct 17 17:06:37 monitor systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 17 17:06:38 monitor systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Oct 17 17:06:38 monitor systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

So I go to look at the logs, but there aren't any?

```
user@monitor:~$ ls /var/log/mongodb
ls: cannot open directory '/var/log/mongodb': Permission denied
user@monitor:~$ sudo ls /var/log/mongodb
```

Nor is there anything in the database folder

```
user@monitor:~$ sudo ls /var/lib/mongodb
```

I haven't changed anything in the config, but am posting it here just to confirm:

```
jon@monitor:~$ cat /etc/mongod.conf
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:
```

So what gives?

OS info:

```
user@monitor:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
```

Comment: signal=ILL means your CPU can't run that version of MongoDB